# In Core Data, should I put the more restrictive or less restrictive predicate first?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

```
-(NSPredicate *) predicateForExactMatch
{
    enum typeOfAutocompleteNew toc = [[self class] typeOfAutoComplete];
    NSPredicate * predictNameMatch=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K==[cd]%@",NSStringFromSelector(@selector(strNameofPlace)),self.strCurrentKeyword];
    NSPredicate * entryTypeNameMatch=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K==[cd]%@",NSStringFromSelector(@selector(strEntry)),@(toc)];
    NSPredicate * final = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predictNameMatch,entryTypeNameMatch]];
    return final;
}
```

Which one is better?

```
    NSPredicate * final = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predictNameMatch,entryTypeNameMatch]];
```

or

```
    NSPredicate * final = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[entryTypeNameMatch,predictNameMatch]];
```

Here, predictNameMatch is definitely far more restrictive. At most 1-2 are exact match. entryTypeNameMatch match like 25% of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you the exact reference because I am writing this on the phone, but I am fairly sure that putting the most restrictive predicate first was recommended at some WWDC Core Data session.

Comment: I think so too. I need someone that can make sure and then explain why. It seems that the secondary index don't really work or that coredata has no compound indexes.

Answer (score 2):

If it matters, test it and measure it.

I suspect that *in general* [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046582/2998) is right but performance optimisation is a dark art and the only way to be sure is to find out...

Comment: When in doubt, ask stack over flow.

Answer (score 1):

The most restrictive predicates should come first. In a compound predicate like this one, the predicates are evaluated left to right, and processing ends as soon as the result is known. In your case you have a logical AND, so if the first predicate is false, the second one will be skipped (since it's unnecessary). So, if the first predicate has hardly any matches, you'll almost never need to evaluate the second one.

It's exactly the same kind of shortcut that happens in an `if` conditional. If you're use `if (a && b)`, and `a` is false, then `b` won't be evaluated.